# Missing assemblies with mono 3 MVC web app

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I've installed the freshly released Mono 3 and MonoDevelop on my Mac, and I was keen to get a simple MVC web application working with razor view pages.

When I File-New-Solution up a MVC 3 Web Application (razor), the thing doesn't compile, giving the error:

`The type or namespace GlobalFilterCollection could not be found`

It's because 2 references are not working - System.Web.Helpers and System.Web.WebPages. When I look at these in the references list in MonoDevelop, they are red with "Assembly not available" - looking at the references in more detail it seems I'm referencing system.web.mvc 2.0.0.0, whereas everything else is 4.0.0.0. Can anyone advise?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually got mine to run by referencing the System.Web.Mvc.dll found in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/4.5/

I also had to bring over System.Web.Helpers.dll from a Windows box and update the Web.Config using one generated by Visual Studio.

There's probably a better way to do this (please be a better way), but figured I'd pass on what I found.

Comment: not entirely sure what's going on, but when i reopened mono develop, it prompted to install updates, after which all mvc3 stuff has gone. pfft.

Comment: Mine does that too. It keeps wanting to update to an older version of Mono which wipes out 3.0. I just ignore the update and/or keep re-installing.

Comment: Yup, re-installing gets it back, and your manual location of those dlls works too. But it feels like we're the only 2 devs in the world doing this :)

Comment: Then I'm number three, I guess :P

Comment: Where is this /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/4.5 at?? Apparently no one that works with mono has issues besides us lol. Or if they do they need no documentation

Comment: @Chazt3n, did you install the beta version of Mono 3.X? http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Comment: I got 3.0.1. Working fine now. In my case, if I have the app running when I add references it will work, but if it's not actively debugging it doesn't detect them. Very odd but hey, works wonderfully.

Comment: Just to clarify. I have 3.0.1 but cannot find System.Web.Helpers.dll. You have to bring it over from a windows box? I can't find it in the mono framework on my Mac.

Comment: I've got a fresh monodevelop install `v3.0.3.2`, new solution using built-in example, when I run I get `System.Web.Helpers` and `System.Web.WebPages` **"Assembly not available for Mono / .NET 4.0 (in Mono 3.0.10)"**

Comment: same issue here, @BrockHensley-FKAdirt. Just that I am using Xamarin

Answer (score 1):

Add packeges "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC" and "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages" from NuGet.